# google assistant on raspberry pi 3 screen conectting

Tags: raspberry-pi3, monitor, google-assistant-sdk

I have installed on raspberry Pi3 Google Assistant every thing is fine works perfect.

**But when I try to ask to show me a picture or to open youtube is telling me that the monitor is not connected**

how can I fix this, to connect the monitor on raspberry pi whit google assistant

thanx

Comment: This is not a coding question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Google Assistant SDK doesn't provide support for displaying contents.